# Python Script to Produce Difference Between Files and Resolve DNS Query for the Output

Tags: python, regex, difflib, dnspython

I wanted to write a python script that gives me the difference between two txt files that contain list of domains.

Below is my script that I was able to create.

```
import difflib

file1 = open("2.txt").readlines()
file2 = open("diff.txt").readlines()
with open ('diff.txt', 'w', encoding = 'UTF8') as diff:
    for line in difflib.unified_diff(file2,file1,n=0):
        for prefix in ('---','+++','@@'):
            if line.startswith(prefix):
                break
        if line.startswith('+'):
            diff.write("New DNS Entry:\n{}\n".format(line[1:]))
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            diff.write("Removed DNS Entry:\n{}\n".format(line[1:]))
```

Since `unified_diff` produces context and characters like +++, --- & @@, I have modified my code to omit this and disabled context.

The output I receive from the above code is as follows:

```
Removed DNS Entry:
-- 

New DNS Entry:
++ 

Removed DNS Entry:
example.com
```

As seen above, the output titles anything with a `-` as "Removed DNS Entry" and anything with a `+` as "New DNS Entry" and stops at very first iteration of a line change between two txt files (although there are multiple changes beyond example.com)

The output I'm expecting is that any line that starts with a `+` should be grouped together and titled "New DNS Entry" and similarly any line that starts with `-` should be grouped together and titled "Removed DNS Entry"

Eventually, the group of "New DNS Entries" should display their appropriate DNS resolution.

Any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: can you kindly add the two input text files, will help us run some code samples against it.

Comment: File content is list of domains/subdomains in the form of example.xyz.com. Pick anything of your choice, you should be able to see the same output using above code.